# Bada development in Linux

Tags: bada

The Bada site list the Windows OS as a system requirement for installing the Bada SDK.

Is it possible to create Bada apps using Linux?

Comment: But i think they said mac and linux will be supported for sdk 2.0

Answer (score 3):

It's not supported by Samsung, but it is possible to run Bada IDE and Simulator on Linux using Wine. There was a problem with communication between IDE and the Simulator, but I believe it is possible to get it to work.
But as far as I know, there are no drivers for the Wave phone, so you won't be able to test your apps on the device.

More info and discussion here: http://forums.badadev.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=82

Answer (score 0):

Samsung announced that upcoming 2.0.0 will support GNU/Linux , else you can try to port the toolchain to start ...

Some links about it (in french) : 
http://blog.newlc.com/tagged/bada

Tell us

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, native Linux / OS X support will only be released later (if at all, I would add) - with the current release of the official 2.0 SDK, there's only a Windows version. (Nevertheless, it does run under Parallels and also accesses the connected hardware.)

Answer (score 0):

It's still not supported by Samsung, but I have combined the toolchain from opensource.samsung.com with some reverse engineering to create this: https://github.com/epi/bali-sdk